# "A first post" -- makes sense or not?

Tags: word-choice, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I once knew a person who titled the first post in his blog, "A first post."

It was immediately pointed out to him that correct usage is "*The* first post." To that he responded: Well, every blog has its first post, and this post is no exception, so this is just *a* first post (among first posts of all blogs).

Neither that person nor the other people were native English speakers.

I wonder, does that rationale makes sense? How does "A first post" sound like for a native speaker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with your first-poster. Both are possible.

> I made **a** first post on my blog today.

Other people make first posts on their respective blogs too.

> I made **the** first post on my blog today.

This one is fine as well; now the implicit context is only *my* blog.

> I made **my** first post on my blog today.

This is possible, since it is *my* first post on this blog; but it is a bit awkward, because you have *my* twice. You could use *My First Post* as a title, though.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds fine to me, for the reasons given.

We have a first step, a first word, a first kiss, etc.

Comment: +1; I see nothing wrong with "a first post" and it could also be used as a subtle pun on the nubs who post "first!"