# Should the article that comes after ‘There is” always be “a” or “an”?

Tags: grammar

I found the following sentence in a reference book of English grammar, titled “These are the weak points of Japanese on English grammar - 日本人は英文法のここを間違える” edited by Japan IR and published by DHC Publishing in 2006:

> “Example: There is *a* first time for everything.
>
> Though you may be tempted to use “the” for “first time,” here you must
>   use “a,” because  it is a grand rule to use “a” after “There is.” The
>   composition,  “There is” always demands “a,” and “first time” just
>   follows its demand.- P.52

I didn’t know such a grand rule – A noun after “There is” should be accompanied with an infinite article exhists. Is it true? I used to write “There was the following article in the New York Times.” Was I wrong?

Comment: It doesn’t sound right. One can say, “There’s the doorbell now,” or “There’s always the Army.”

Comment: Yoichi-san, this has nothing to do with "there is", and everything to do with "first". I hope the answers will address that in more detail. We had at least one related question a while back, too: [“A first post” — makes sense or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22880/a-first-post-makes-sense-or-not)

Comment: @RegDwight: I think your comment needs more explanation. You can certainly say "the first time", but not "the first time for everything".

Comment: Well. I have to write the publisher about their misleading readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's "reference book of English grammar" is misleading. No native speaker would ever say/write *"it is **a grand rule** to [do something]*. As regards that supposed "rule", it's demolished by...

> [*There is hope*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22there%20is%20hope%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [for us yet.]
>    [*There is the matter of*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22there%20is%20the%20matter%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [actual usage to be considered].

Whilst it's true we normally say *"There is **a** first time for everything"* (not *"...**the** first time..."*), this has nothing to do with "rules of grammar" - it's just the established idiomatic usage in that precise construction. In a slightly different construction, we normally use ***the***...

> [*There is always the next*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22there%20is%20the%20matter%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22there%20is%20always%20the%20next%22&oq=%22there%20is%20always%20the%20next%22&gs_l=serp.3...217372.226592.0.226917.24.22.2.0.0.2.180.1345.20j2.22.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.xIJq2qEKY6I&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1262&bih=866) [example to be considered].

---

Turning to the specific question as asked, there's nothing at all wrong with OP's example...

> *There was the following article in the New York Times.*

...*providing* the article itself is either quoted or referenced *in the text following*. But it *would* be "non-standard" if ***the*** were simply replaced by ***a*** with no other changes. Note that if we remove the word ***following***, it would be valid with either ***the*** or ***a*** - it largely depends on whether or not the speaker wants to emphasise/single out "the" specific article he's talking about.

Comment: You saying Wallace isn't a native speaker?

Comment: @Edwin: I know nothing of "Wallace", but if he wrote OP's cited text, I suggest he's hopelessly out of touch with modern usage. I can find half-a-dozen instances of ["it is a grand rule"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it+is+a+grand+rule%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, but all are over a century old, and most are *two* centuries old. But I admit I use *no native speaker* loosely to mean ***almost** no native speaker*. OP would not do well learning at the feet of *this* "master" (if indeed he purports to be so).